# Is there a way to make the test suite stop , with the answer Success? Using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, protractor

I have a problem, I want to make my test stop in the middle 
of the execution of "IT", so proceeding to the next "IT". I've found two ways to do this, one using pending () or fail (), however I want to do something like that, but instead of returning it "pending" or "fail" to return success.

Suite testing

```
const URLs = 'https://www.google.com/';
const searchGoogle = 'music eletronic youtube';
const searchYoutube = 'nerdologia';

describe('Start simulator False', () => {
  it('Enter youtube ', () => {
    browser.driver.get(URLs);

    browser.sleep(5000);

    browser.driver.findElement(by.name('q')).sendKeys(searchGoogle);
    browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('/html/body/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div/div[3]/center/input[1]')).click();

    browser.sleep(1000);

    // browser.pause();
    browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('//*[@id="rso"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/a')).click();

    isAngularSite(false);
  });
  it('Search to data random youtube', () => {
    browser.sleep(6000);
    element(by.id('search')).sendKeys(searchYoutube).then((visible) => {
      if (visible) {
        throw 'Error';
      }
      element(by.id('search-icon-legacy')).click();
    });
    // browser.driver.findElement(by.css('[#search]')).sendKeys(searchYoutube);
    browser.sleep(6000);
    browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('//*[@id="contents"]/ytd-video-renderer[1]')).click().then(() => {
      throw 'Stop the test';
    });
    browser.sleep(6000);
    browser.executeScript('document.querySelector(\'#movie_player > div.html5-video-container > video\').pause();');
  });
})
```

Protractor.conf.js

```
const SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;
const AllureReporter = require('jasmine-allure-reporter');


exports.config = {
  // The address of a running selenium server.
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

  // Spec patterns are relative to the location of this config.
  specs: [
    'webapp/e2e/spec/*.js',
  ],

  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxInstances: 5,
    marionette: true,
    acceptInsecureCerts: true,
    chromeOptions: { args: ['--disable-extensions'] },
    // browserName: 'chrome',

    // chromeOptions: {
    //     args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
    //         "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1366x768" ]
    // }
  },


  // capabilities: {
  //   directConnect: true,
  //   browserName: 'chrome',
  //   marionette: true,
  //   acceptInsecureCerts: true,
  //   chromeOptions: {
  //     args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
  //       '--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--window-size=800x600'],
  //   },
  // },

  //     capabilities: {
  //     'browserName': 'chrome',
  //         'chromeOptions': {'args': ['--disable-extensions']}
  //     //   browserName: 'chrome',
  //     //
  //     //   chromeOptions: {
  //     //       args: [ "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=800,600" ]
  //     //   }
  // },

  onPrepare() {
    global.isAngularSite = function (flag) {
      browser.ignoreSynchronization = !flag;
    };

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
      displayFailuresSummary: true,
      displayFailuredSpec: true,
      displaySuiteNumber: true,
      displaySpecDuration: true,
    }));
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new AllureReporter({
      resultsDir: 'allure-results',
    }));
    jasmine.getEnv().afterEach((done) => {
      browser.takeScreenshot().then((png) => {
        allure.createAttachment('Screenshot', () => new Buffer(png, 'base64'), 'image/png')();
        done();
      });
    });
    beforeEach(() => {
      originalTimeout = jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL;
      jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 1800000;
    });
    afterEach(() => {
      jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = originalTimeout;
    });
  },

  allScriptsTimeout: 180000,
  getPageTimeout: 180000,


  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    onComplete: null,
    isVerbose: false,
    showColors: true,
    includeStackTrace: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 1800000,
  },
};
```

how to run faster

```
protractor protractor.conf.js  --specs='nameOfFile.js'
```

Answer (score 2):

Protractor uses the [Jasmine testing framework](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/ed955e56a839d7f69da43acb6755763220d3681d/docs/frameworks.md#using-jasmine) out of the box.

Jasmine allows for the [testFunction](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/global.html#implementationCallback) passed in a [Specs](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/global.html#it) to be declared to receive a callback.

Even so that your test is synchronous, converting it to an asynchronous one allows for you to control when Jasmine moves one to the next test.

You can use this to let Jasmine know to move on by invoking this argument. *e.g.*

```
it('Enter youtube ', (done) => {
  // some operations that you care about running
  done();
  // other operations that you like to skip
});
```

Comment: I don't know why the done() is undefined, i don't know what's wrong

Comment: the answer is right. @Dantinho maybe you pass `done` to one `it` block and try to use in another one?

Comment: Yes, it's correct, but when I try to call "Done ()" it comes as undefined. I think I've found a solution to solve the my problem. Thank you.